# Smallest twin-prime-pair exceeding $10^{1000}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I found the twin-prime-pair $$\large 10^{1000}+9705092\pm 1$$ with PARI/GP.

Is this the smallest twin-prime above $10^{1000}$ ?

A general question to the search of twin primes : 
The prime number theorem states that the probability, that the number $n$
is prime, is roughly $log(n)$. So, to find a prime above a random prime $n$, 
you need to check about $log(n)$ numbers to find the next prime.

- But what is the probability that a number $n+2$ is prime, if the number
  $n$ is prime ? The probabilities are not independent. In particular,
  if $n>3$ is prime, $n+2$ is odd and the probability that it is divisible
  by $3$, is $\frac{1}{2}$ and so on. But I do not know how to derive the
  desired probability from that.

Comment: It looks like the first twin over 10^1000 to me.

Comment: Did you make a calculation or is this simply an intuition ?

Comment: Lol, I ran it through my software.  `twin_primes(start,end)` returns the start value of twin primes between the values.  Only one result when given start=10^1000 and end=10^1000+9705094.  The implementation isn't that great, but it didn't take too long.

Comment: It is probably much faster than PARI/GP.

Comment: I wrote a better implementation, so now it takes 2 minutes to go from n=10^1000 to n+10^7.  The old one was finding primes using `next_prime` looking for twins, which is about 3x faster than Pari doing the same at this size.  The new code does a fairly deep partial sieve, removes all non-twin candidates, then BPSW on the remaining candidates (skipping the second if the first fails).  It's a lot fewer expensive primality tests.

Comment: I also elimanted numbers with very small factors, but my computer still needs very long with my PARI-implementation. Maybe I should look for updates for PARI, or my computer is simply too old (1-2 years seems to be an eternity today). Thanks anyway for checking!

Comment: I think to do the same with Pari would mean writing C code, but maybe a Pari guru would know better.  The partial sieve efficiently removes anything in the range with small factors, in this case removing anything in the range with factors under 265 million in under 2 seconds.  This skips lots of tests especially since we don't have to test a number unless its twin is also a candidate, and only test the twin candidate if the first actually is prime.  Getting primes in a range can also use a sieve, but can't optimize away the twin-related tests.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page on twin primes that gives a possible estimate for the probability that $x$ is the lower of a twin prime pair:

$$\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{p(p-2)}{(p-1)^2}\frac1{(\log x)^2}\\
\approx\frac{0.66016}{(\log x)^2}$$

https://primes.utm.edu/top20/page.php?id=1

The formula was conjectured by Hardy and Littlewood.

Comment: You missed the factor $2$. The approximation $$\frac{1.32}{log(x)^2}$$ works well.